# Elasticsearch 2.2.0 Plugin Security grants

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, java-security

I have an Elasticsearch [opensource plugin](https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin) that needs reflection to inspect the originating address of HTTP requests.

In ES 2.2 they introduced security permissions for plugins, following the [instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.x/plugin-authors.html), I added a grant in the plugin-security.policy file with the following:

```
grant {
  permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
```

Now upon installation of the plugin, I can see this (as anticipated in the docs). So I assume the request for permission is successfully kicking in.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@     WARNING: plugin requires additional permissions     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
* java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html
for descriptions of what these permissions allow and the associated risks.
Installed readonlyrest into /elasticsearch/plugins/readonlyrest
```

However, from my function that actually uses reflection, **still** see this error...

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugin.readonlyrest.acl.blocks.rules.impl.HostsRule.getAddress(HostsRule.java:76)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugin.readonlyrest.acl.blocks.rules.impl.HostsRule.match(HostsRule.java:130)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugin.readonlyrest.acl.blocks.Block.check(Block.java:104)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugin.readonlyrest.acl.ACL.check(ACL.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugin.readonlyrest.ReadonlyRestAction$1.process(ReadonlyRestAction.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController$ControllerFilterChain.continueProcessing(RestController.java:265)
```

Is there something missing? I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to wrap the reflection code in `AccessController.doPrivileged()` :)

Comment: In which file ?

Comment: in the Java source code, you just need to wrap any code that makes use of the permissions inside that AccessController.doPrivileged(... some lambda that executes the code...). @MathiasConradt Are you developing an ES plugin by any chance? Which one?

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was switching from Open JDK to the oracle JDK